# blank screen when login

Tags: php, html

I need some help with my code. It works on XAMPP on my computer but when it's live on my server it won't work all I get is a blank screen. You can have a look what happens at `<a href="http://www.redhotessentials.com/prototype/pages/login.php</a>` put username allanallan password allanallan and you can see what happens thanks

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['email'])) {
//Connect to the database through our include 
require("db.php");

$email = stripslashes($_POST['email']);
$email = strip_tags($email);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($email);
$password = preg_replace("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "", $_POST['password']); // filter everything but numbers and letters
$password = md5($password);
// Make query and then register all database data that -
// cannot be changed by member into SESSION variables.
// Data that you want member to be able to change -
// should never be set into a SESSION variable.
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE email='$email' AND password='$password' AND emailactivated='1'"); 
$login_check = mysql_num_rows($sql);
if($login_check>0){ 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){ 
        // Get member ID into a session variable
        $id = $row['id'];  
        session_register('id'); 
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        // Get member username into a session variable
        $username = $row['username'];   
        session_register('username'); 
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        // Update last_log_date field for this member now
        mysql_query("UPDATE members SET lastlogin=now() WHERE id='$id'"); 
        // Print success message here if all went well then exit the script
        header("location: endlessnails_blog.php");

        exit();
    } // close while
} else {
// Print login failure message to the user and link them back to your login page
  print '<br /><br /><font color="#FF0000">No match in our records, try again </font><br />
<br /><a href="index.php">Click here</a> to go back to the login page.';
  exit();
}
}// close if post
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Login to your profile</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/main4.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- Form Validation -->
function validate_form ( ) { 
valid = true; 
if ( document.logform.email.value == "" ) { 
alert ( "Please enter your User Name" ); 
valid = false;
}
if ( document.logform.pass.value == "" ) { 
alert ( "Please enter your password" ); 
valid = false;
}
return valid;
}
<!-- Form Validation -->
</script>
</head>
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<?php include("nav.php"); ?>
<body>
       <div id="container">
        <div id="box3">
     <div align="center">
       <h3 id="login2"><br />
         <br />
       Log into Endless Nails Blog<br />  
       <br />
       </h3>
     </div>
     <div id="loginformmove">
     <table class="style7" align="center" cellpadding="5">
      <form action="index.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="logform" 
id="logform" onsubmit="return validate_form ( );">
        <tr>
          <td class="style7"><div align="right">Email Address:</div></td>
          <td class="style7"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" maxlength="64" /></td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
          <td class="style7"><div align="right">Password:</div></td>
          <td class="style7"><input name="password" type="password" id="password" size="30" maxlength="24" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td class="style7">&nbsp;</td>
          <td id="login3"><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="login_pad" /></td>
        </tr>
      </form>
     </table>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  </div> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You must have spent forever with your question...

Comment: Indent code by four spaces. Don't use `\`backticks\`` except for inline code.

Comment: white screen of death = error checking turned of and or error display off. you cant debug, if you cant see the errors.

Comment: where is db.php? I checked it and got a 404 error

Comment: do you have error reporting enabled?

Comment: db.php doesn't exist, that's whats giving the blank page, if a required file isnt found, the whole page crashes. try using include and the page will still show up but the user will not login as there is no thing as db.php

Comment: Thanks for the response. db is used to connect to the database I can query the database using echo so I'm connect to the database. If you have any more idea that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the enctype from your FORM attributes, since you are not Uploading files, just use the method="POST"

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  Silly mistake I thought I had the error code in don't know how I missed that.  I can now see the errors

Comment: fixed, I was printing two headers the header had been sent already so  putting header("location: endlessnails_blog.php"); = fail. I also need to put session_start(); works good now thanks everyone for your help.